# Change bgcolor on TD where that contain a with a onClick that contain XXX

Tags: jquery, html, search, onclick

I need a jQuery script that can change color on all td if it contain a onClick that contain "BG5". 
It need to work on IE7. I have tried $("a:contains('BG5')").css("background","#F6CED8");

Is this possible?

They TD get the effect by a push on buttom

```
    <tr bgcolor='#F2F2F2'>
    <td>2011-04-18</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td align="center"><a href="#" onClick="edit('BG5')"><img src="../img/icon/skruenogle.png" border=0 alt="Delete corr"></A>
    <td align="center"><a href="#" onClick="disregard('BG5')"><img class="click" src="../img/icon/redcross.png" border=0 alt="Delete corr"></A></td>
</tr>

<tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
    <td>2011-04-18</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td align="center"><a href="#" onClick="edit('1A1')"><img src="../img/icon/skruenogle.png" border=0 alt="Delete corr"></A>
    <td align="center"><a href="#" onClick="disregard('1A1')"><img class="click" src="../img/icon/redcross.png" border=0 alt="Delete corr"></A></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, what you're trying to do is change the background colour of every `tr` element that contains an `a` tag which has the string "BG5" in an attribute named `onClick`.

If that's along the right lines, try something like this:

```
$("a").filter(function() {
    if($(this).attr("onClick")) {
        return $(this).attr("onClick").indexOf("BG5") !== -1; 
    }
}).closest("tr").css("background-color", "blue");
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/xzHAX/) using your HTML and the above jQuery. Basically what that does is get all the `a` elements, filter them so we are left with only those which contain the string "BG5" in the `onClick` attribute, gets the closest `tr` element to those, and sets the background colour.

An important thing to note would be that the `attr` method is case sensitive, so you'll want to make sure you are consistent with your HTML!

On a separate note, you really shouldn't be using the `bgcolor` attribute, [as it's deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#adef-bgcolor). CSS should always be used instead. Also, there's a couple of `td` elements which have not been closed in the code in your question. That may just be a typo in the question, but worth a mention just in case!

Comment: Hi...Can see you example works fine but there are somthing wrong with the key in IE with the real one i do not work in IE7. http://jsfiddle.net/xzHAX/

Comment: What do you mean by "there are something wrong"? *What* is wrong?